# React Native | How to combine multiple views into one view using Animated?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I want to combine multiple views into one, using React Native Animated Component.

### Details

- Each View should be located in the different position.
- Each View should be increasingly expand width, height in the owns position.
- All Views should be combined into one which is located in the middle of position of all Views when reached to max width, height.
- The change of the size(width, height) of all Views should be determined by the zoom of screen. (You don't worry about it because I had already knowledge about this way.)